# (How) can I join a workgroup while remaining on a domain in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, domain, workgroup

I learned (the hard way) that joining a workgroup while on a domain removes you from a domain. I need the computer connected to the domain so it can connect it's internet, but I would like to connected to the workgroup for file/printer sharing, etcetera. To re-join the domain I need administrative privileges (on the domain) which I don't have.

Comment: Don't you need administrative permissions to leave a domain?

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is that you can't - the system is either a domain member or a workgroup member.

Long answer is that you probably don't need to.  You can probably get away with just keeping it on the domain.

I have never had any problem accessing shared resources hosted by non-member systems from a domain-joined system; that is to say, you don't need to be a member of the workgroup in order to use its shared resources - you just need to have valid credentials for the non-domain server you're accessing.

Likewise, I've never had any trouble accessing shared resources hosted on domain-joined servers from non-domain systems; typically, you just need to provide domain-based credentials when accessing the particular resource.  For instance, you could use this command line to map a network drive hosted on a domain member server from a non-domain client system:

```
net use x: \\memberserver\sharename /user:domain\username
```

You can use this approach with graphical tools as well.

I can't guarantee this sort of thing will work in all network configurations, but it's always worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Upon joining a domain, your system uses the domain for things such as authentication and group policy. The way Windows accomplishes browsing is by essentially using the NETBIOS version of the domain as a workgroup.

If you are able, you can give the non-domain workgroup the same NETBIOS name as the domain (so if your domain is `example.com` use the workgroup `example`) which will enable browsing in the way I think you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: You can't.

You can have either a domain or a workgroup.

Comment: Are there any alternaives?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this reg key DWORD in computer with "WorkGroup" and setting the value to one changes that. I can now connect from "DOMAIN" with no problem!

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system\LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be done...[from this link 'how to' at Tom's hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/23334-42-notebook-work-domain-home-workgroup#8095511)

> I do this kind of thing all the time, and it's not too difficult.
>   First off, even if your machine is on a domain, there is nothing
>   stopping you from connecting to network resources in your workgroup
>   even if your machine is not in that workgroup. As long as you can
>   resolve the names of your home or church computers, you can connect.
>
> If you want to go to the next step and have quite different profiles
>   for home/church and work, you can do this:
>
> Leave your computer in the domain used at work. Go to Administrative
>   Tools -> Computer Management -> Local Users and Groups, and create a
>   user. This is the user you will use for home and church work. Of
>   course, you'll need local admin access to your machine to do this. You
>   may also want to add this new user to the local Administrators group.
>   Also, you can even use the same username as you do at work.
>
> So when you get to work, you log in as fiber_todd, selecting your work
>   domain in the "Domain" drop-down at the point of login. When you are
>   at home our church, you log in as fiber_todd but select the local
>   computer in the "Domain" drop-down. That way you won't affect your
>   work profile when at home and you can even have different web proxy
>   settings that match your needs at home if they are different from
>   work.

Comment: Welcome to superuser, the aim here is to provide an as complete answer with the link as a backup source. this makes it easier and quick to read but mainly it leaves a record should the link be changed (broken) at any time, but thank-you for your first answer.